# Dired search and replace is throwing no results

Tags: dired, query-replace

I am trying to quickly search and replace in multiple files using dired. The steps I follow are from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270930/using-emacs-to-recursively-find-and-replace-in-text-files-not-already-open/271136#271136) (Chris Conway's and Frank Henard's answers), I am pretty sure the instructions are correct since it seems like I am the only person having this problem.

To simplify the problem, the steps I am doing are as follows:

- Open a folder in dired
- Mark a file with **`m`**
- **`Q`** to search and replace in the marked file, this command will ask for two arguments, in the search query argument I type **`div`**, and in the replacement query argument I type **`foo`** (to replace div with foo).

After I do these simple steps, the search throws no results, the buffer says:

> No matches for: div

I know plenty divs are spreaded all over the file. Perhaps I am not entering the arguments in the correct format, I tryed many things, like enclosing the string in quotes or double quotes, and running emacs with the -q argument in the shell to disable my dotfile. The instructions looked pretty simple, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Emacs version: 25.1.1

Comment: What OS are you on? I believe this uses `grep`, so it may be an issue with what grep executable it is finding or what args are being passed. Also, try to reproduce this after starting with emacs with -Q (ie with the default settings, no local config.)

Comment: Fedora 25. Yes, I ran emacs with -q and -Q, the problem persists. `M-x rgrep` works fine, but dired's Q option doesn't.

Comment: Are your values for `grep-find-ignored-files` and `grep-find-ignored-directories` a factor? (Although they also affect `rgrep`.) FYI the implementation for the `Q` binding is completely new in Emacs 25. 24.5 runs `tags-query-replace` whereas 25.1 uses the new `xref-collect-matches` and `xref-query-replace-in-results`.

Comment: @Drew I think you should add this as an answer instead of a comment so it can be marked as the proper answer.

Comment: @Fabman: OK, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @phils said in a comment, Emacs 25.1 no longer uses `dired-do-query-replace-regexp` for `Q`. It uses `dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace` for `Q`.

(It shouldn't, IMHO, but it does.)

Try `M-x dired-do-query-replace-regexp`. If that works, you can just bind it to `Q` to have `Q` act the same as it used to.

Comment: Do you know why `dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace` fails to find matches for regexps that work just fine with `dired-do-query-replace-regexp`? More than that, I'm just replacing string literals, e.g. `TEST_STRING -> teststring`, and it's failing to find matches.

Comment: @Andy: No, sorry; I don't know. I haven't investigated `d-d-f-r-a-r`. (I don't even use it, myself.) But if you have a concrete query that you think should succeed but which fails, then consider filing a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. (For the example you mention, are you taking care of case-sensitivity? Could that be the problem?)

Comment: Finally I can search and replace using regexps that contain newlines again. Thank you!

Comment: @taranaki: Consider filing a bug report / enhancement request for the xref stuff, if it doesn't let you do that: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.